# Send data to pc over bluetooth or wifi

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-zero-w, connection

I am working on a project where i have a motion sensor connected to a arduino connected to a raspberry pi and when the motion sensor detects movement i turn of my **Windows** pc. I want to connect the raspberry pi to my pc with bluetooth, i have a 'raspberry pi zero w 1.1' so it does have bluetooth. But i dont know how to connect it to my pc. **And** i also need to send data to my pc (over this bluetooth connection). It only needs to be just one byte only to tell the computer movement was detected (then ill turn the pc off using python)

Does anyone know how to set up this connection and send data?

**Btw:** if this is easyer with wifi thats fine as wel

Comment: What OS is your PC running?

Comment: My pc is running windows, my raspberry pi can be running any os

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming your PC's bluetooth device is `AB:12:34:45:67:78`.
- On Windows reveiver: [Create a COMM port on Windows](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-20605/) - listen mode.
- On the Pi sender: Elevate yourself to `root` or use `sudo`.
- Establish a connection with `bluetoothclt` -> `scan on`, `pair AB:12:34:45:67:78`
- Bind your connection with `rfcomm`

  ```
  rfcomm bind 0 AB:12:34:45:67:78
  ```
- You now have a new entry in `/dev/rfcomm0`
- Send whatever output there.

  ```
  echo "die nasty PC!" > /dev/rfcomm0
  ```
- Do your python magic on the Windows receiver side.

Comment: hciattach, hciconfig, hcitool, hcidump, rfcomm, sdptool, ciptool, and gatttool were [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) in 2017 so I would be cautious of starting a new project with those tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3.9 on your Windows PC then you can create a Serial Port Profile (SPP) client with the Socket library.

There is more information about Bluetooth with Python sockets at: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/